# Issues Changing Input Field Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to change the default startdate on the Google Finance webpage to "Dec 23, 2001" via the below code, but it does not persist and reverts back to "Dec 23, 2014". How can I ensure the date persists?

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/finance')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys('IBM')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


url = browser.current_url

historical = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a")
historical.click()


elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name("startdate")
elem2.click()


elem2.send_keys('Dec 23, 2001')
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the text field before setting it's new text. This can be achieved using the `clear()` method.

The below code should work (note the use the `clear()` before using `send_keys()`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/finance')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys('IBM')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

url = browser.current_url

historical = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a")
historical.click()


elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name("startdate")
elem2.click()

# clear the text box
elem2.clear()

elem2.send_keys('Dec 23, 2001')
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Hope this helps.